# Event for controller changing model in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is there an event or a hook that should be used to capture when a controller is initialized after being instantiated, or reinitialized for a specific route?

I've already tried `init()` - but my controller is only instantiated once for the life of the application, but supports multiple models depending on the route.  What I need to capture is when the model of the controller changes, or some moment after instantiation when the route changes.

I've also tried setting a computed property, but it isn't really appropriate, since I need an event to fire a function when the model changes - not only when the property is called.

Any help is very appreciated.

---

Edit:  Aha! I completely looked over the fact that I can set `observes()` on my function, so that it will fire when the model changes.

So, my answer was to do the following:

```
dependency: function() {
    console.log('the model has changed');

    //...other stuff...
}.observes('model')
```

Comment: take a look here http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/

Comment: Zaemz, please put that as your answer and mark it as accepted (when available).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my edit:

> Aha! I completely looked over the fact that I can set observes() on my
>   function, so that it will fire when the model changes.
>
> So, my answer was to do the following:
>
> ```
> dependency: function() {
>     console.log('the model has changed');
>
>     //...other stuff... 
> }.observes('model')
> ```

Comment: Hey, is it a good practice to use observe, i read somewhere that is adds to the performance.

Comment: @whyAto8 I don't see any reason why it would be a bad idea.

The API has actually changed in recent versions of Ember (I haven't used it in quite some time now.)

I'll do some reading and update my answer.  For the moment, I would defer to the documentation:  https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/object-model/observers/